# Video manipulation using ffmpeg library

Tags: android

I need a proper documentation and explanation of the ffmpeg library files that we can use to do programming so as to make a video editor that is capable of adding effects in video and merging 2 different  video files.I want to make the editor for android,although i got the android specific ffmpeg files from http://bambuser.com/opensource but i am unable to utilize them for my purpose.
I tried a simple c program in devC++ using the header files like avcodec.h avformat.h given in ffmpeg but getting linker error for function like av_register_all,av_open_input_file.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! You might want to revise this question. There seem to be multiple questions (ffmpeg+effects, linker error in devc++, etc.) You might want to focus on the biggest problem and explain that to us. Give us a bit more detail. Also, I would advise against using DevC++. It's very very out of data and no longer actively developed.

Comment: Amongst other things, you have to convince DevC++ to use an android gcc (such as from the ndk) rather than the default compiler which produces programs to run on the PC.

Comment: I simply want to make a c project using ffmpeg to manipulate video(like file conversion).Suggest me proper libraries and documentation for that